# Flutter, is it possible to add a Icon inside TextFormField 'hinttext' prorperty?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

is it possible to add a Icon inside TextFormField 'hinttext' prorperty?

I know about this shown below

```
InputDecoration(
 prefixIcon: Icon(
  Icons.lock_outline,
    )
 )
```

but what I want currently is hint Icon

so the if users click the hint then 'hintText' and 'hintIcon' would be disappeared

is there a way to achieve this? thanks

Comment: you  can use stack widget to achieve this behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want by using states.

```dart
InputDecoration(
  prefixIcon: _showHint ? IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.lock_outline,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        _showHint = false;
      });
    },
  ) : Container(),
);
```

To reset the `_showHint`, you'll want to use [FocusNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) to listen to events. The documentation of `FocusNode` describes that.